# Unable to make android create a notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to have android display a notification when a button is pressed. I have followed an online tutorial but nothing happens when I press the button. Looking online I cannot find anything that would suggest what is wrong and I am new to android.

I have one class

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendNotification(View view) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "M_CH_ID");

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("Hearty365")
                .setContentTitle("Default notification")
                .setContentText("Random words")
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and one layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendNotification"
        android:text="@string/do_it" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate if someone could explain to me what the issue is or possibly link me to a tutorial that is accurate as of API 29.

Comment: which version of android OS you are testing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

```
  public void sendNotification(View view)  
    { 
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
                        new NotificationChannel("M_CH_ID", "M_CH_ID", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Test");
                nm.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "M_CH_ID");

            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add)
                    .setTicker("Hearty365")
                    .setContentTitle("Default notification")
                    .setContentText("Random words")
                    .setContentInfo("Info");

            nm.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create notification channel for Oreo or later before creating notify.

```
 public void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                String description = context.getString(R.string.channel_description);
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("M_CH_ID", "M_CH_ID", importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no OnClickListener on your Button, you should use something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendNotification();
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendNotification(View view) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "M_CH_ID");

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("Hearty365")
                .setContentTitle("Default notification")
                .setContentText("Random words")
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: is having android:onClick="sendNotification" in my layout not sufficient?